# Update existing data in a content type from JSON file in Drupal

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting, migrations, location

I have to import Latitude and Longitude data in to a Geofield that was added to an existing Content type.

Source Info 
The json feed contains a lot of data fields including the Longitude, Latitude info, Title and a unique ID

I tried the following:

[Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module 
It requires an existing guid to match which I found no way to work around with existing nodes. The need here is to update. In this case the nodes already exist so I am unsure how to map them to GUID which is available only for Feeds imported nodes.

[Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) module 
I am planning to explore Migrate module. What I looked at seems like this may be a complex solution and better suited when source and destination are different databases rather than the same.

Thus let me know if there is a straightforward way to import data to a new field on an existing content type. If it can support geodata, that would be a bonus.

Comment: Just to clarify, do the existing nodes share a property (field) with the json feed? If so, why can't you use that as your GUID with feeds? If not, how do you know which json object goes with which existing node?

Comment: I thought GUID show actually be a primary key id, Is there a way to map it to the node id? Also it is on multiple fields that they mach instead of just 1 field